# which one has better numerical properties

Tags: numerical-methods

Given $ w,x,y \in \mathbf{R^{n}}$

which one has better numerical properties?

(1) $ w = z - (x \cdot y^{T}) \cdot z$

(2) $ w = z - x \cdot (y^{T} \cdot z)$

First one needs more FLOPS (thus more possible floating point arithmetic errors) and storage to be solved.
Which is more robust to perturbations?

Comment: If you set aside floating point issues, then they're going to be exactly the same in terms of sensitivity to *mathematical* perturbations.